# TypeORM ManyToOne multiple relations

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typeorm

I have this database structure. I have a parent that has a many-to-one relation to MyComponent. The parent itself is not in use, only the children using the "components" property of the parent.
[image]

Each child can have multiple MyComponents, but a single MyComponent can only have a relation to one specific child.

My initial plan was to do something like this:

```
// MyComponent.ts
@Entity()
export default class MyComponent {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(type => Parent)
  public propName: Parent
}
// Parent.ts
@Entity()
export default class Parent {
  ...
  @OneToMany(type => MyComponent, myComponent => myComponent.propName)
  public myComponents: MyComponent[];
}
// child1.ts
@Entity()
export default class child1 extends Parent{
  ...
}
```

However, when I try to set a relation between child1 and MyComponent, I get the following error: `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_yadayadac\". The conflict occurred in database \"db_name\", table \"dbo.parent\", column 'id'.`

How can I set MyComponent to have a relation to the different children and not the Parent entity?